# How can I keep “approximate” date data points?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a web app that displays some *products* with their *release date*. Some *dates* are complete (for example, `'2017-09-05'`) and some are not (for instance, `'first 2018 quarter'`, `'2018 september'`, `'2019'`).

The existing database is built on MySQL and I want to keep requests “simple”.
Sometimes I need to request (a) *released products*, sometimes (b) *future products*, and sometimes (c) *all products*.

**The questions**

How can I (1) retain and (2) manipulate these incomplete *date* data points? In the same `date` column? In which format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard" way.  You need to invent something, then write app code to handle it.  Some thoughts:

- Strings like what you suggest.  Pro: displays nicely; Con: hard to parse.
- Strings, but more like `2018Q1`, `201809`, or whatever.  Pros/cons:  Somewhat readable; somewhat parsable.
- `DATE`, with the day of the beginning (or end?) of the period, plus another column that says day or month or quarter or annual.  That could be an `ENUM` or some other technique.  Pro: somewhat sortable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The sortable point is very important for me. I thought about `2018-XX-XX` but there is no quarter information.

Comment: How about `2018-04-01-Q1` and `-H1` and `-Annual`.  All in a `VARCHAR`.